# How to import and use npm package in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I am new to EmberJS and I want to import and use the crypto-js in my EmberJS app, I used `ember install crypto-js` to install the package, then add those lines in `ember-cli-build.js` to add them to ember build to use SHA256 function:

```
  app.import('node_modules/crypto-js/core.js');
  app.import('node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js');
  app.import('node_modules/crypto-js/sha256.js');
```

And I can see that in browser, assets/node_modules has the crypto-js folder with above 3 files. However I still got `Could not import module 'crypto-js'` error. How to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `app.import`.

As long as you have `ember-auto-import` installed, or you are using `embroider` (which defers to `webpack`), you can follow the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

```
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256';
import hmacSHA512 from 'crypto-js/hmac-sha512';
import Base64 from 'crypto-js/enc-base64';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. It is an old project and after I installed `ember-auto-import` and `webpack` i got many build errors. I dont want to waste time on fixing them, but finally i got it worked:

```
  app.import('node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js',{
    using:[
      {transformation: 'amd', as: 'CryptoJS'}
    ]
  });
```

Then I can import it and use in other .js files, like this:

```
import CryptoJS from 'CryptoJS';
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a file called crypto-js.js in the shims folder and add this code

```
import 'crypto-js/core';
import 'crypto-js/sha256';

export default window.CryptoJS;
```

In your ember-cli-build.js file, add this linne:

```
app.import('vendor/shims/crypto-js.js', { using: [{ transformation: 'cjs', as: 'crypto-js' }] });
```

in your component, controller or model, you can import the library and use the SHA256 function like this

```
import crypto from 'crypto-js';
const hash = crypto.SHA256("Message to hash");
console.log(hash.toString());
```

Comment: this is not recommended since ~2018, I think. folks can use ember-auto-import to follow instructions as documented on package's readmes.  The build system details are abstracted away from app-devs, for the most part.